# IP automatically changing to different ip of different location

Tags: ip, dynamic-ip

I'm living in Chennai,India. My ISP is Bharti Broadband. Why does my IP address change to IBM ip address(9.0.45.0 ), just before 10 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Your IP is allocated by your ISP when you login for each (broadband) session.
So it can change each time you login.
But `9.0.45.0` does not sound right.

---

You could get another IP address if you connect to a VPN tunnel somewhere.
That could be a private address (usually is).
Yet, `9.0.45.0` does not sound right at all -- can you paste the output for '`ipconfig /all`'?
(I assume you are working on a Windows system -- else, it would be '`ifconfig`').
<sub>If you want to scrub your output, I just want the names of all interfaces and

the lines for IP Address, Subnet Mask, Default Gateway and DNS Servers for each interface.</sub>

---

Finally, the entire `9.0.0.0` Class-A is is [owned by IBM](http://www.ip-adress.com/whois/9.0.0.0).
So, any incorrect value in that range will appear to be IBM -- you don't get IP addresses that end with a '0' in the last octet normally, which makes me pretty sure you have an error somewhere in your data.